# Why Is my script freezing up when I hit enter?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

The majority of the Add-on is good but whenever I hit enter (which is, in my opinion, the most common way to submit a form, for example, a login form), but all it does is blank out.

I've tried linking the script with a `onkeydown` like so:

```html
<div onkeydown="handle(event)">blagh blagh blagh</div>
```

but I still get the same results:

```html
<html>
<form id='myForm' style="font-family:Georgia;">

<table>
<tr><td><h2>Enter your Password</h2></td></tr>
<tr><td><p>DO NOT HIT ENTER ON YOUR KEYBOARD!!!!!</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name='password' type='password' value="" onkeypress="handle(event)"></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="submitbuttcontainer"><img id="submitloader" style="display:none;" src='https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-S87nMBe6KWE/TuB9dR48F0I/AAAAAAAAByQ/0Z96LirzDqg/s27/load.gif' /><input id="submitbutt" type='button' onclick='showWorking();google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).decodeForRequest(document.getElementById("myForm"));' name="Submit" value="Submit"></div></td></tr>
</table>

</form>
<script>
function onSuccess(obj) {
  document.getElementById('submitbutt').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('submitloader').style.display="none";
  if(obj.status == 'success') {
    google.script.host.closeDialog();
    browser.msgbox('Access Granted', browser.buttons.OK)
   }
   else { 
    browser.msgbox('ALERT!!','!OOF!','Incorrect Password. Please retry', browser.buttons.OK);
   }
}
function showWorking() {
  document.getElementById('submitbutt').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('submitloader').style.display="block";
}

function handle(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 13)
document.getElementById('submitbuttcontainer').click();
        }
</script>
</html>
```

All I'm trying to do is get the form to submit when I hit enter and not blank out. I always hit enter to submit a form but in this case all it does is blank out the form and all I have is whiteness.

Here's the link for the complete source code (don't know if this will work because I'm in a school district):

https://script.google.com/a/bcsdschools.net/d/1_YUx4ZP3qEWVcFMc-MvfEYX2S34r7-b4M0iRlE_JQa81T3ZubN5OeISa/edit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem**

Hitting `enter` key results in form submission (which is explicitly forbidden in Apps Script due to its client-to-server communication implementation).

---

**Solution 1 - handle inputs individually**

Add `preventDefault()` to a `keydown` event if key is `enter` (btw, `keypress` event is deprecated, see [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) on MDN, use the `keydown` / `keyup` instead):

```
var ENTER_CODE = 13;

function handle(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === ENTER_CODE) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('submitbuttcontainer').click();
  }
}
```

---

**Solution 2 - handle form submit**

You can listen for a `submit` event on your form instead and invoke `preventDefault()` as the only statement in event handler or handle form submission at the same time if you expect form to be submitted on `enter` key hit:

```
//assumption: form is initiated elsewhere in code;
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  //handle submission;
});
```

You can also prevent all forms from being submitted to make the setup flexible:

```js
(() => {
  const { forms } = document;

  Object.values(forms).forEach(
    form => form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => e.preventDefault())
  );
})();
```

Or, alternatively, use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/11407695) and register one listener on the `document` since the event bubbles up:

```js
document.addEventListener("submit", (e) => e.preventDefault());
```

---

**Suggestion**

Please, use `addEventListener` instead of `on[event name here]` attributes. This way is much more flexible and has the benefit of being concise and easy for others to read.

**References**

1. Handling forms in Apps Script [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)
2. Why use `addEventListener`? MDN [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener)

Comment: how did i not know that "keypress" is deprecated >:(

Comment: Zachary, it is actually deprecated for quite some time, but this isn't obvious unless you use MDN or specifications themselves for reference when needed. For example, w3schools lists it without any warning of deprecation

Comment: Btw, have you been able to successfully solve the issue? Both mine and Cooper's answers boil down to the use of `preventDefault()` added as first statement in `submit` event handler

Comment: @ZacharyCross - huh, glad to know you are still here and fixed it :) The easiest way is to use the solution #2 and just overwrite all "submit" events - they are pretty much useless in GAS as you can't actually "submit" forms

Comment: and I just started learning about addEventListener and I kinda wish I would have used them instead. cause you are right about them being more flexable

Comment: @ZacharyCross - well, once you enter frameworks territory (i.e. Angular), you will suddenly find out that you are using a version of what you did before (under the hood everything is different, though).

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to try to give you a complete answer, but I have to admit that I may know less about event handlers than you.  But this seems to work for me.

aq4.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.onload=function() {
        preventFormSubmit1();
      }
      
      function preventFormSubmit1() {
        console.log('preventFormSubmit1');
        var form=document.forms['myForm'];
        form.addEventListener('submit',function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      }
           
      function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        console.log('handleFormSubmit');
        var first=document.forms['myForm']['first'].value;
        var last=document.forms['myForm']['last'].value
        var sheet=document.forms['myForm']['sheet'].value;
        console.log('%s,%s,%s',first,last,sheet);
        if(first.length>0 && last.length>0 && sheet.length>0) {
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function(msg){
            var div=document.getElementById('output');
            div.innerHTML=msg;  
            var inputs=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
            inputs[0].focus();
            for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
              inputs[i].value='';
            }
          })
          .processForm(formObject);
        }else{
          alert("Invalid or Incomplete Data");
        }
      }
     
      console.log("MyCode");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <input type="text" name="first" /> First<br />
      <input type="text" name="last" /> Last<br />
      <select name="sheet">
        <option value="Sheet1">Sheet1</option>
        <option value="Sheet2">Sheet2</option>
      </select> Sheet<br />
      <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

aq1.gs:

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(formObject.sheet);
  sh.appendRow([formObject.first,formObject.last]);
  return Utilities.formatString('First: %s<br />Last: %s<br />Sheet: %s', formObject.first,formObject.last,formObject.sheet);
}

function runOne() {//This loads the dialog
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq4').setWidth(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "My Form Example")
}
```